# Access iPhone's camera from UIWebView using HTML 5

Tags: iphone, html

I am looking to find a way to shoot and record video using the iPhone's camera using HTML 5. I referred this document. 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/
I have tried using the HTML Media Capture API as told in several posts. But I cannot access the camera. I'm using the following code in my HTML file which is rendered in an UIWebView.

```
//A choose file button which is actually disabled came up.
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" id="capture">
```

which didn't work.

And this code,

```
//Didn't worked
window.navigator.getUserMedia('audio, video', function(){
                                                  alert('Success');
                                                  }
                                                  , function(){
                                                  alert('Error');
                                              });
```

and finally this one,

```
//This came up as [object Navigator]
alert(navigator);
//This came up as undefined.
alert(navigator.device);
```

**Is video capture in iPhone actually possible via HTML 5?** Does this means that Media Capture API of HTML 5 is not yet fully deployed? If so will it be in near future? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently.  You will have to use a framework like AppMobi or Apache DeviceReady(Phonegap) to get access to the native camera via JavaScript in a UIWebview.

Comment: Does this means that Media Capture API of HTML 5 is not yet fully deployed? If so will it be in near future?

Comment: No idea.  The spec hasn't been ratified and vendors are implementing parts at will.  They were quick to implement WebDB (sqllite) which has since been dropped for IndexDB, but WebDB is still available on mobile devices.