# iOS HTML Camera Preview input documentation

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, camera, ios-camera

Is there any Apple documentation for this (used in a UIWebView):

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access iPhone's camera from UIWebView using HTML 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725203/access-iphones-camera-from-uiwebview-using-html-5)

Comment: It's NOT a duplicate. I'm not looking for code samples. I'm looking for documentation.

Comment: There's a link to the w3 documentation in the question.

Answer (score 1):

since UIWebViews are used by Safari, you'll find what you're looking for right here : [Safari HTML Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Introduction.html).

You may also want to take a look at the [Supported Input Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/InputTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008055-SW1) section.

Jordan

Comment: Sorry, neither of those things document what I'm looking for.

Comment: Oh okay... Sorry then. Maybe you should have a look to the W3C on the other SO's question, as suggested by David.